# Where to put MD5 function to make it work?

Tags: php, echo, md5

I need to send md5 hashed password to database.

```
<?php
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
print_r($_POST['name']);
if (empty($username)){
    echo "Username should not be empty"; die();
}
if (empty($password)){
    echo "Password should not be empty"; die();
}
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "db_account";

//create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
  die('Connect Error ('. mysqli_connect_error() .') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
} else{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO t_account (name, pwd)
  values ('{$username}','MD5({$password})')";
  if ($conn->query($sql)){
    echo "Account was created successfully!";
  }
  else{
    echo "Error: ". $sql."<br>". $conn->error;
  }
  $conn->close();
}
?>
```

When I fill register form with password for example 123456 it sends it to database like this (MD5)123456 but not as a hashed code.

Also after successfull registration it only shows text after @echo, is possible to redirect user to another page?

Comment: md5 is **terribly out of date** - do **not** use it. use `password_hash` and `password_verify` to securely store user credentials. also: use parameterized queries to protect your database - filter functions do **not** protect you completely from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yeah I know,but the game accepts passwords as md5 so I would probably need to make it accept different hashed password, well and i dont have skills for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the PHP md5() function:

```
$password = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'));
```

Also your statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO t_account (name, pwd)
values ('{$username}','{$password}')";
```

I strongly suggest you use prepared statements. Not hard to learn and time well invested.